# how to store textbox values in array using jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have two text boxes with the same name `control_text` but their values are different. I want to store all my text box values in an array using jQuery.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="control_text" placeholder="Text Label Image" class="required" id="control_text" value="firstvalue" />
<input type="text" name="control_text" placeholder="Text Label Image" class="required" id="control_text" value="secondvalue" />
```

JavaScript

```
var test_arr = $("input[name='control_text']");
$.each(test_arr, function(i, item) {
    // i = index, item = element in array
    alert($(item).val());
});
```

The above code is displaying the values of text boxes individually. I don't want to alert these values individually, I want to alert both at once with comma separator similar to
`(firstvalue, secondvalue)`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its also possible on submit, to get the results in an array format via the serialize Array function - http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/  $('form').submit(function() {
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
  return false;
});

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var arr = $("input[name='control_text']").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

**A side note:** elements in a single page should have *unique* IDs, so check your markup for validity.

Comment: It's worth mentioning you'll need to apply `.get()` additionally, to get real js array.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, I always forget about it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var newArray = [];
$( "input[name='control_text']" ).each(function() {
    newArray.push($( this ).val());
});
console.log(newArray);
```

you can also achieve it using .each function.

Comment: I've tried a dozen answers and this is the only one that worked for some reason... Thank you.